# Python: UDP echo server asyncore ; socket closing after send

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I'm trying to write a UDP server that echos data back using asyncore.dispatcher_with_send

The problem i have is that when i set the buffer and call self.send(self.buffer), it seems to call handle_close and closes the socket.

```
import asyncore, socket,

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send): 

def __init__(self):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.bind(('192.168.0.10', 1452))
    self.buffer = ''
    self.recvData = ''


def handle_close(self):
    self.close()

def handle_read(self):
    print self.recv(8192)
    self.buffer ='a'

def handle_write(self):
    if self.buffer != '':
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


if __name__ == '__main__':

The_Server = Server()
asyncore.loop()
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use sendto and to make sure the sendto address was explicit.

```
import asyncore, socket,

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send): 

def __init__(self):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.bind(('192.168.0.10', 1452))
    self.buffer = ''
    self.recvData = ''


def handle_close(self):
    self.close()

def handle_read(self):
    print self.recv(8192)
    self.buffer ='a'

def handle_write(self):
    if self.buffer != '':
        sent = self.sendto(self.buffer,('192.168.0.9',1452))
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


if __name__ == '__main__':

The_Server = Server()
asyncore.loop()
```

Comment: You also could have called `self.connect(('192.168.0.9',1452))` in `__init__`, and continued to use `.send()`.